# How can I debug loss of monitor signal after kernel upgrade?

Tags: debian, xorg, nouveau

I'm running Debian Testing, and with the upgrade to the 4.13 kernel, my monitor stopped working. It shows the initial lines of startup, but then switches modes (the resolution changed in previous kernels) and goes blank - "No Signal".  Removing `quiet` from the GRUB line doesn't change that. I'm running a Nvidia NVS 310 with the Nouveau driver. Switching back to previous kernel versions, e.g. 4.12, works fine.

How can I debug this issues? What log files should I be looking at? Should I report a bug, and if yes, to whom? Debian kernel package, Xorg package, Nouveau package, something else?

**Edit:** I've compared the entries in `kern.log` between booting with 4.12 and 4.13, and these lines appear immediately after trying to switch to the frame buffer in 4.13: https://pastebin.com/raw/ThpeyqPQ So it looks like a bug in the nouveau kernel module, correct?

Comment: First thing to do is to `ssh` in from a second computer, and after boot with loss of signal, look at `dmesg`. This sounds like the problem already occurs when the kernel module switches to framebuffer mode, before X starts, so `Xorg.log` won't help.

Comment: Thanks, that was a good pointer. I think I've found something in the `kern.log`; see edit.

Comment: Whereever the bug is, it crashes hard. Try a [bugreport](https://nouveau.freedesktop.org/wiki/Bugs/) and see if the nouveau developers have any ideas.

Answer (score 1):

Install the [`kerneloops`](https://packages.debian.org/buster/kerneloops) package it will automatically submit a kernel oopses bug to `oops.kernel.org` through the `kerneloops.service` service.

```
kerneloops.service - Tool to automatically collect and submit kernel 
crash signatures
```

the `man kerneloops`:

> [kerneloops](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/kerneloops/kerneloops.8.en.html) - program to collect and submit kernel oopses to oops.kernel.org
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> `kerneloops` is a program that collects kernel crash information and then submits the extracted signature to the oops.kernel.org website for statistical analysis and presentation to the Linux kernel developers

[Documentation on ubuntu wiki : Debugging Kernel Oops](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingKernelOops)